# Event.currentTarget from 'a href' is always the body element in ajaxStart function on Chrome

Tags: jquery

I am using the `ajaxStart` function and I am trying to access the `currentTarget` property of the function's parameter event, but if the element that triggered the ajaxStart is a `<a href` than I get the body as the `currentTarget` and `activeElement` instead of the `a`. This only happens in Chrome. I have to mention that if i use a button than i get the right element

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (e) {
    var trigger = $(e.currentTarget.activeElement);
});
```

Is there a workaround for this behavior?

Comment: I didn't think the `ajaxStart` event had any info about the element that triggered the AJAX call.

Comment: `e.currentTarget` is the element the "event" was bound to (same as `this`), so it's `document`.  Therefore `e.currentTarget.activeElement` is just `document.activeElement`.  My guess is that by the time the `ajaxStart` function is triggered, the `<a>` tag is no longer focused.

Comment: there is no other code that i execute before ajaxStart. I manage to handle it by adding a listener to the click event of all a href elements and set a global variable which stores the element that was clicked.